# ElasticSearch API Request not getting a response

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, search

I am trying to pass a request body through the API gateway to an ElasticSearch  endpoint on Amazon. But I am not getting a response that reflects the request.

I have:

- setup the GET method in the gateway,
- passed the Authorization-header, and
- used the "Input passthrough: Yes".

the response I get back from ES is as if I send no query.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide more information about how you are building the GET request.

Answer (score 0):

Use `POST` and not `GET` to send `body` in request (your query is in body I suppose) or put all in `head`. Not sure which client are you using, but I had problems with body in `GET` with `Spring`

from docs:

> Both HTTP GET and HTTP POST can be used to execute search with body.
>   Since not all clients support GET with body, POST is allowed as well.

[Search request body](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html)

Comment: yes indeed - the query is in the request body. I will see if I can make it work with POST